# Is there way to load sqlite database from resource in QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, sqlite, qml

I did databese using DB Browser, I really enjoy it, but I don't know how to load it in QML, I know how to create new db with table at appdata/local/appname/qml/db, but I don't know how to load my db from resources, can someone tell me? I only found it:

```
var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("QQmlExampleDB", "1.0", "The Example QML SQL!", 1000000);
```

And It's working, but if I want to load my db

```
var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("food.db", "1.0", "The Example QML SQL!", 1000000);
```

It's not working, why?

Comment: Are you actually using *both* C++ and Javascript?

Comment: Yes. QML, C++ and JS (in this same project)

Comment: And the code you want write is which?

Comment: Code which I want to write is Javascript

Comment: And this particular question has nothing to do with C++?

Comment: I removed C++ tag.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, currently this is not already exposed in QML.

For deploying your own persistent Db you might use the C++ API which is available in the `sql` module (add `QT += sql` in your .pro file). 
You will find several examples about how to use it in QtCreator. Also, make sure you read the docs before using it.

Keep in mind that if you add it to the resources it will only be readable.
If you want it to be writable you should:

1. ship it with some other mechanism (which is platform-specific) in your .pro file
2. add code to your application to move the dB to a platform-specific writable location

Here is an example of what to include in the .pro file:

```
georecords.files = sestosg.sqlite
georecords.path = "./"
macx {
    georecords.path = "Contents/MacOS"
}
android {
    georecords.path = "/assets"
}
QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += georecords
INSTALLS += georecords
```

Then in your application you should manage the conditions about when and where to copy the db, e.g. as per the example below. Make sure to import the relevant headers. This supports OSX, Android and iOS. Other platforms might have different requirements.

```
QString dbName = "sestosg.sqlite";

// determine source path
QString dbSourcePath = QSysInfo::productType() == "android" ?
            "assets:/" + dbName :
            QDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()).filePath(dbName);
QFileInfo dbSourceInfo(dbSourcePath);

// determine destination path
QDir writableLocation(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation));
if (!writableLocation.exists()) {
    writableLocation.mkpath(".");
}
QString dbDestPath = writableLocation.filePath(dbName);
QFileInfo dbDestInfo(dbDestPath);

// determine if the source db has changed
bool dbSourceUpdated = dbSourceInfo.lastModified() > dbDestInfo.lastModified();

// copy or replace db if needed
if ((!dbDestInfo.exists()) || dbSourceUpdated) {
    QFile::remove(dbDestPath);
    if (!QFile::copy(dbSourcePath, dbDestPath)) {
        qCritical() << "ERROR: source db " << dbSourcePath << " not copied to "<< dbDestPath;
        return false;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "db successfully copied or replaced to " << dbDestPath;
    }

} else {
    qDebug() << "dest db " << dbDestPath << " already exists";
}

// make db writable
QFile::setPermissions(dbDestPath, QFile::WriteOwner | QFile::ReadOwner);
qDebug() << "current db: " << m_dbPath;
```

Finally, you will need to create a class with methods to connect/read/write from the db and expose that as an instance or component to QML, perhaps via a model.